# Error : Field job in required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am a beginner with spring batch, and I developped a simple project with it . I am getting the error.

```
Description:
Field job in com.example.demo.DemoApplication required a bean of type 
'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' in your 
configuration.
```

Here is my code,  I have just one class :

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
    public void perform() throws Exception {
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, params);
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping me to find the mainly cause of this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you do not have a `Job` bean defined in your application context or the job is not found by Spring Boot.

Make sure the configuration class in which you define your batch job is in the package (or sub-package) scanned by your Spring Boot app (which is `com.example.demo` according to your sample).

Comment: I am facing this issue when I remove in-memory database H2 from POM and @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }) in my configuration. Using H2 working fine perfectly. How can we launch a job without a in-memory DB

Answer (score 2):

Check if you added the Spring annotations to Job. @Service if it is a service class,
@RestController if its a rest api, @Repository if it is a repo ...

Answer (score 2):

Add the annotation  @EnableBatchProcessing to your Spring main class

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. I checked the spring-boot-starter-parent version in pom.xml and used 2.7.9 version. It worked.

Comment: The question was posted 3 years ago and its framework might not same as yours. I guess your advise is upgrading PO's depedencies to newer version. That might be more clear and helpful.